# Why can't Dsovle solve the simplest equation?

Tags: differential-equations

When I want to use Mathematica software to solve the following simple PDE, it cannot be solved.

```
DSolve[D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], x, x, x] == 0, u, {x, t}]
```

And give an error message:

> DSolve::lpdeprtclr: General solution is not available for the given linear partial differential equation. Trying to build a particular solution.

But it is easy to know that it has an exponential solution:

$u=e^{-k^3 t +k x + \theta}$, $k$ and $\theta$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: Mathematica v12.2  evaluates `{{u -> Function[{x, t}, 
    1/120 (120 C[1] + 120 x C[2] + 120 x^2 C[3] - 720 t C[4] + 
       120 x^3 C[4] - 2880 t x C[5] + 120 x^4 C[5] - 
       7200 t x^2 C[6] + 120 x^5 C[6] - 360 t^2 C[11] + 
       120 t x^3 C[11] - x^6 C[11])]}}`

Comment: I also got the polynomial solution through Mathematica, but I couldn't get an obvious exponential solution

Comment: I think the warning message is clear enough. Since your input is just a PDE without any i.c./b.c., `DSolve` first tries to find a general solution, but it fails, so it finds a particular solution. The exponential solution at your hand is another particular solution, that's all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP's question has already been answered by the warning message, there's nothing can be answered here.

Comment: If OP asked e.g. "how to obtain the desired particular solution for this PDE with least effort using _Mathematica_", the question would be definitely on-topic, though.

Comment: BTW, the "simplest" equation has to be `DSolve[y'[0]==0,y,x]`, which `DSolve` can do.

Comment: I suppose the easiest way to produce the desired particular solution is to type `{u -> Function[{x, t}, Exp[-k^3 t + k x + \[Theta]]]}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 And if the solution is required to be deduced from the PDE, then `fg = f[x] g[t]; neweq = DivideSides[D[u[x, t], t] == -D[u[x, t], x, x, x] /. u -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@fg], fg, Assumptions -> fg != 0]; grule = DSolve[neweq[[1]] == k^3, g[t], t][[1]]; frule = DSolve[neweq[[2]] == k^3, f[x], x][[1]] /. C[1 | 2] -> 0; fg /. frule /. grule`

Answer (score 3):

Assume solution is $u=f(x) g(t)$ then

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] + D[u[x, t], {x, 3}] == 0;
usol = u -> Function[{x, t}, f[x]*g[t]]
newpde = pde /. usol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Divide both sides by $f(x)g(t)$ this gives two odes

```
ode1 = g'[t]/g[t] == C[1]
ode2 = f'''[x]/f[x] == -C[1]
```

Solve each and multiply the solutions

```
gSol = g[t] /. First@First@DSolve[ode1, g[t], t]
fSol = f[x] /. First@DSolve[ode2, f[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Simplify a little

```
fSol = fSol /. C[1]^(1/3) -> k^3 /. (-1)^(1/3)*k^3 -> θ
finalSol = fSol*gSol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Expand[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could work on this more if you want the exact same solution you showed

$$
u=e^{-k^3 t +k x + \theta}
$$

by combining and renaming more of the constants shown. This is now just algebra.